# sorting a string using counting sort

Tags: c++

I looked at the counting sort algorithm to sort a string here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-sort/. I have a few questions:

```cpp
#define RANGE 255
```

What is the function of `RANGE`? Why do we have to specifically define the `RANGE` to 255?

```cpp
int count[RANGE + 1], i;
```

Why do we have to declare the size of `count[]` as `RANGE+1`? Why couldn't it be just 256?

```cpp
// Store count of each character  
for(i = 0; arr[i]; ++i)  
    ++count[arr[i]];
```

The array stores the count of the specified digit, but here we have characters in a string, so how does the above code convert the characters to numeric equivalents to be stored in the array?

Comment: i am afraid most of your questions can be answerd by: That site unfortunately promotes bad practices. There is no good reason to `#define` a constant. `memset` is kinda ok-ish but not nice. Using `arr[i]` as stop condition is not wrong but also not nice. Not using `std::array`/`std::vector` in favor of c-arrays is not nice. Don't try to learn C++ from online tutorials but rather grab a good [book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: U could use c++ containers to map strings with integer values and act on integer value keys for counting sort algorithms like redix sorting

Answer (score 0):

1. `RANGE` defines possible keys for counters. Which are `0..RANGE`. It might be arbitrary, but 255 is for having exactly 256 possible values. The same as the number of distinct characters.
2. So we have possible keys 0..255. That is exactly 256. You can hardcode it like this. But since `RANGE` is arbitrary, you may want to change it to 512 for example. In that case, you will need to change the size too.
3. From a logic point string consists of characters, but it is only our minds representation. For C++ string is an array of `char` type. Which is an integer type. Since the international part of [ASCII](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) table uses only values `0..127`. We can safely use these values as array indexes.

Comment: "Which is an integer type with values -128..127" that is wrong. `char` can be either signed or unsigned

Comment: Here we are considering `char` which is signed, not `unsigned char` which is not signed

Comment: no that is wrong. `char` is either signed or unsigned, and either way it is a type distinct from `signed char` and `unsigned char`. You can read about it here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types

Comment: Thank you @idclev463035818 for pointing it out. Removed wrong part of the answer

Answer (score 0):

I would not use that code as a learning example. There are so many errors in it that I wasn't even able to properly compile it.

**What is the function of `RANGE`?**

When you compile your code a special program called a preprocessor runs beforehand. The preprocessor essentially replaces a lot of things. It usually does this based on statements called preprocessor directives and they begin with the "#" symbol. In this case, `#define RANGE 255` is telling the preprocessor to replace every occurence of "RANGE" in the code with "255". For example, the line `int count[RANGE + 1], i` becomes `int count[255 + 1], i`.

**Why do we have to specifically define the `RANGE` to be 255?**

To be completely honest I'm not sure why the code decided to use 255 for `RANGE`. I've tested the code and it works just fine with `RANGE` equal to 114 and it doesn't work with numbers. If you increase the length of the input string "geeksforgeeks" to something much larger then `RANGE` won't be sufficiently large enough.

**How does the code convert the characters to numeric equivalents to be stored in the count array?**

The `char` data type is actually an integer. Every character we use (A to Z, 0 to 9, punctuation, etc) all has a corresponding number. For example the code below will print out the number which corresponds to `a` which is "97".

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char name[] = "abc";

    int a = name[0];

    std::cout << a;

    return 0;
}
```

The line `++count[arr[i]];` simply accesses element `i` in the array `arr` and appends it to the `count` integer array which it can do because `char` is an integer. Once we have it in the `count` integer array it is treated like a normal integer and when we print it out in the console it shows us a number rather than a character.